# Why i am getting Undefined index?

Tags: html, codeigniter, firefox, undefined-index

i am developing an application using CodeIgniter. In my application when i submit the form in firefox 10.0, i got this error

```
Message: Undefined index: adcopy_response
```

But when i submits the form in IE 9. It's working fine my application. No errors found in IE. Can any one. My HTML code is

```
                <table>
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <tr id="row">
                        <td><b>Title:</b></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" style="width:450px;" name="title" value="" />

                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="row">
                        <td><b>Description:</b></td>
                        <td>
                            <textarea style="width:450px;" name="desc" cols="35" rows="10"></textarea>
                        </td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr id="row">
                        <td><b>URL:</b></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" style="width:450px;" name="url" value="" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="row">
                        <td><b>Category:</b></td>

                        <td>
                            <select name="cat">
                                <option value="">Select Category</option>
                                <option value="ajax-tutorials">AJAX Tutorials</option><option value="asp-tutorials">ASP Tutorials</option><option value="asp.net-tutorials">ASP.NET Tutorials</option><option value="codeigniter-tutorials">CodeIgniter Tutorials</option><option value="css-tutorials">CSS Tutorials</option><option value="html-tutorials">HTML Tutorials</option><option value="javascript-tutorials">JavaScript Tutorials</option><option value="jquery-tutorials">jQuery Tutorials</option><option value="ms-sql-tutorials">Ms SQL Tutorials</option><option value="mysql-tutorials">MySQL Tutorials</option><option value="php-tutorials">PHP Tutorials</option><option value="programming-tutorials">Programming Tutorials</option><option value="wordpress-themes">Wordpress Themes</option><option value="wordpress-tutorials">WordPress Tutorials</option><option value="xml-tutorials">XML Tutorials</option>                                </select>

                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="row">
                        <td><b>Prove you're not a robot</b></td>
                        <td>
                            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.solvemedia.com/papi/challenge.script?k=hse4RWPEOMayq3QzRQiUZTnTtVkI8Jmf"></script>

<noscript>
    <iframe src="http://api.solvemedia.com/papi/challenge.noscript?k=XXXX" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br/>
    <textarea name="adcopy_challenge" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="adcopy_response" value="manual_challenge"/>
</noscript>                            </td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr id="row">
                        <td>
                                                                <input type="hidden" name="ok" value="1" />
                                                            <input type="hidden" name="by" value="seekphp" />
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Tutorial" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </form>

            </table>
```

and CI code is

```
function submit(){
    $privkey="XXXX";
    $hashkey="XXXX";
    $data['err'] = "";
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required|trim|xss_clean|htmlentities');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('desc', 'Description', 'required|trim|xss_clean|htmlentities');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('url', 'URL', 'required|trim|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cat', 'Category', 'required|trim|xss_clean');
    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
    } else {
        $title = $this->input->post('title');
        $desc = $this->input->post('desc');
        $url = $this->input->post('url');
        $cat = $this->input->post('cat');
        $by = $this->input->post('by');
        $ok = $this->input->post('ok');
        $solvemedia_response = $this->Captcha_model->solvemedia_check_answer($privkey,
                                        $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                        $_POST["adcopy_challenge"],
                                        $_POST["adcopy_response"],
                                        $hashkey);

        if ($solvemedia_response->is_valid) {
            if($this->Tutorial_model->add_tut($title, $desc, $url, $cat, $by, $ok) == TRUE){
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', "Tutorial has been added successfully.");
                redirect(base_url().'user/submit', 'refresh');
            } else {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('err', "Tutorial may already exist or there is an error while submitting tutorial.");
                redirect(base_url().'user/submit', 'refresh');
            }
        } else {
            $data['err'] = "Incorrect Captcha.";
        }
    }

    $data['cats'] = $this->Category_model->get_all_cats();
    $this->load->view("user/submit_view", $data);
}
```

and when i print_r($_POST);
i got the following

```
Array ( [title] => test title [desc] => test desc [url] => test url [cat] => javascript-tutorials [adcopy_challenge] => 2@hse4RWPEOMayq3QzRQiUZTnTtVkI8Jmf@Szx1Cc29gNUENU8bgrSwY39APTC4lJjoCYJjyXvIJi2gPnq5tZIMpr0JgoGocL4bVHKrYt6Zyx3w-DAv2nYsjYiaeT-0C9Ec297zPussZKqXHDAdWTWT7ZcC1MklNV75-TPQzGDGu0yUgkDQWcRup.sNAOGBvK0cXCac1RzQ7T6adyI4bmcrNTpt7ANEEq2-1QcBgS8Uky6FxFHeFyGMDgzlJvqGyrBJfDRBNwroHBUXGHC1Jza9b54IS1.0E9kwlqZUOeBX9EomSEVcgrS6gA [ok] => 1 [by] => seekphp [submit] => Submit Tutorial ) 1
```

Comment: Spontaneous guess: The form field in question is in a `<noscript>` section. One of the two browsers does not submit fields in there if Javascript is active. Otherwise, could you maybe narrow this down to the relevant code parts and include some debugging information you have attempted?

Comment: @deceze I have update the question and paste the print_r($_POST) debugging info

Answer (score 1):

Even if you *think* you know what should be in the `$_POST` array, don't assume it if you want to avoid notices. Codeigniter has the Input class to make this easier:

```
$_POST['doesnt exist']; // generates undefined index notice
$this->input->post('doesnt exist'); // returns FALSE, no notice
```

Most importantly, you have the input in a `<noscript>` tag, so the browser may not send the value.

> But when I submit the form in IE9 it's working fine, no errors found.

Chances are you either have javascript turned off, or IE is misbehaving (quite likely).

Answer (score 0):

I think `$_POST["adcopy_response"]` is being used on Captcha Model but it is not in `$_POST`

Answer (score 0):

Finally i resolved the problem by removing `<table> <tr> <td>` tags

Comment: Yes, looking at it again, your HTML is invalid do to the `<form>` being nested inside the `<table>` (and probably more). Different browsers misbehave differently in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Place your hidden tag out of `<noscript>` tag. only When script is disabled in your browser, code inside the `<noscript>` will work. Disable script in your browser and then run it will perfectly work.